# why can I not remove this dkms module?

Tags: linux, dkms

I'm trying to remove this dkms module but am running into trouble.

I run

```
sudo dkms uninstall rtl8812au/4.3.14
```

and I get

```
Error! The module/version combo: rtl8812au-4.3.14
is not located in the DKMS tree.
```

However, when I run `dkms status`, I get

```
8188eu, 1.0, 4.13.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.13.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
mt7610u_sta, 1.0, 4.13.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg: added
```

and when I go into the Makefile.dkms in the following folder,

```
y9@y9-aspire:~/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux$ ls
clean            core       ifcfg-wlan0  Makefile       README.md
contrib          dkms.conf  include      Makefile.dkms  runwpa
CONTRIBUTORS.md  fetch.sh   Kconfig      os_dep         wlan0dhcp
contributors.sh  hal        LICENSE      platform
```

I see

```
modname := rtl8812au
DKMS := dkms
modver := 4.3.14
```

I just want to know how I can clear my dkms modules. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of normal operations gone wrong, you can always delete dkms add-ons by hand, with sudo or as root.

Normally the modules sources are installed by `make install` under  `/var/lib/dkms/` in a directory with the corresponding name, probably named `rtl...something`. Just delete that directory.

You have also to delete the corresponding compiled file module under `/lib/modules/KERNEL_VERSION/updates/dkms/`  where KERNEL_VERSION is your current kernel. The file should be called `rtl...something.ko` or similar.

Once done that, you can either try to rmmod the module or falling that, reboot.

No module and corresponding dkms anymore in the system.

While not critical, the module dependencies also need to be updated after deleting the module. Run:

```
sudo /sbin/depmod -a
```

Comment: After doing all that, is sill get with `modinfo rtl8812au`:
`filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8812au.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'rtl8812au': No such file or directory`.  Where does it get the filename from? Is there anything else i still need to clean up?

Comment: @Alexey updated the answer, should solve your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use: `sudo apt purge realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms`